# NSXMLParser parser:parseErrorOccurred: not called on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, ios7, nsxmlparser

I have a very strange issue on iOS7.

I use standard NSXMLParser.
On iOS6 everything works just fine - when XML is valid as well as when NSData is zero bytes or contains invalid bytes.

```
self.dataParser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
[self.dataParser setDelegate: self];
[self.dataParser parse];
```

On iOS7 parser works as expected only when it has a valid XML data.
If data is zero bytes, none of the delegate methods are called.

Please help me find a direction to look to. Thanks.

UPD.
All delegate methods are implemented (they work well on iOS6). 
I could check if data contains non-zero bytes (and data == nil), but I also must handle non-valid XML situations...

Comment: What about checking the *return value* of the `parse` method?

Comment: @MartinR this is a very good option, thank you!

Comment: As mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752793/nsxmlparser-degelate-method-parseerroroccurred-is-never-called-on-ios-7?noredirect=1#comment29667025_19752793 
I ended up implementing the `didFailWithError` of the `NSURLConnection` rather than the `NSXMLParser` delegate. However you seem to be much luckier than me in case of asking the same question and getting better answers! (: 
Thanks for the comment and link! (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that on iOS 7 `parser:parseErrorOccurred:` delegate method is not being called when data is zero bytes or is not valid in `UTF8` encoding.

It became a revelation to me that I don't have to use `parserDidEndDocument:` and `parser:parseErrorOccurred:` methods to detect finish of parsing, I can just check return value of `parse` method!

It's like I've been blind all these years :)

Big thanks to Martin R.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check if your `data` is OK. You should implement delegate method:

```
parser:parseErrorOccurred
```

and check what was wrong and handle an error.

In your case you only should check `if(!data)`.

Comment: Of course all delegate methods are implemented. I decided not to flood with it. And method you mentioned is exactly the one I need to be called - and it isn't!
I could check if data contains non-zero bytes (which is obviously not the same as data == nil), but I also must handle non-valid XML situations.
Posted an update to the question.